# How to set a default port for ASP.NET Core Angular app

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I created a dotnet core project with the template **ASP.NET Core with Angular** using the dotnet CLI

`dotnet new angular`

Now, whenever I run the application using `dotnet run` command, angular serves with a different port each time.

I tried setting the default serve port in angular-cli.json

```
"defaults": {
  ..
  "serve": {
    "port": 4200
  }
}
```

doesn't work though.

I couldn't find any documentation online, so where can I set the default port?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, turns out, the changing port doesn't matter as I could access the Angular app from the url http://localhost:5000

```
$ dotnet run
Using launch settings from /Users/raviteja/Desktop/CSharp/SignalR-Angular-ChatApp/Properties/launchSettings.json...
: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[0]
      User profile is available. Using '/Users/raviteja/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      Starting @angular/cli on port 56082...
Hosting environment: Development
Content root path: /Users/raviteja/Desktop/CSharp/SignalR-Angular-ChatApp
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      > SignalR_Angular_ChatApp@0.0.0 start /Users/raviteja/Desktop/CSharp/SignalR-Angular-ChatApp/ClientApp
      > ng serve --extract-css "--port" "56082"

      ** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:56082, open your browser on http://localhost:56082/ **

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      Date: 2018-05-31T23:44:11.061Z

info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      Hash: 7f8c3d48fb430eed2337
      Time: 13815ms
      chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 3.85 kB [entry] [rendered]
      chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 50.5 kB [initial] [rendered]
      chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 549 kB [initial] [rendered]
      chunk {styles} styles.bundle.css (styles) 119 kB [initial] [rendered]
      chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 9.5 MB [initial] [rendered]


info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
      webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

I thought the port specified in this line is the one I should use to access the Angular app

```
Starting @angular/cli on port 56082...
```

turns out, it's not the one I should be using

from [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=netcore-cli#create-a-new-app):

> The app starts up an instance of the Angular CLI server in the
>   background. A message similar to the following is logged: NG Live
>   Development Server is listening on localhost:, open your
>   browser on http://localhost:/. **Ignore this message**—it's **not**
>   the URL for the combined ASP.NET Core and Angular CLI app.

But when I was trying to access http://localhost:5000, I was getting an SSL error, upon more digging, I found this line in Startup.cs

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

After adding this condition, it's working fine now and I'm able to access the Angular app at http://localhost:5000

```
if (!env.IsDevelopment())
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

Comment: Note: If you use port 5000 and you _touch_ an Angular file, it will re-compile, but the browser WILL NOT reload automatically.

Comment: I ran into this problem today. The solution created using command <<dotnet new angular>> having the issue. While tunning the app using <<dotnet run>> the angular app is not opening up in the same port. Do I need to add anything extra in the url to open the angular app?

Answer (score 17):

The SpaServices are taking the "ng serve" command from the package.json file and adding a random port before running the command.  In Windows, to get around this add your own port command and the suffix "&REM" which tells the command processor that anything after that is a comment.

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve --hmr --o --port=5002 &REM",
  ...
  }
```

In the command window you will see something similar to the following when it's processed:

```
  > ng serve --hmr --o --port=5002 &REM "--port" "58198"
```

Comment: I should point out that the reason I wanted a fixed the Angular port was so I could configure CORS on the C# back end for development. A better approach is to configure the ng server to be a proxy. That way the application is sending REST requests to the same port it was served from. Google "Angular Proxy to Backend" to find the appropriate solution for the version of Angular you are using. (This applies to other frameworks, including Vue.JS.)

Comment: if the spa is using a random port, then why is there an application url variable with a fixed port (launchSettings.json)?

Comment: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices: Error: Option "port" was already specified with value 5002. The new value 26498 will override it.

Comment: Hi @fdsfdsfdsfds. I am not sure how the project this related to was originally scaffolded but was probably around the era of Angular 4. On this project the Angular app was served directly to the browser by npm. It appears that new Angular projects now route via Express to npm using HTTPS by default and so this work around is no longer required. Judging by the responses left on my original answer, I suspect that more than a few others had this issue too.

Comment: If you are here because you set the port in the package.json but are still getting the error:
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0] Option "port" was already specified with value ####. The new value #### will "override" it." 
You MUST add the &REM to the end of the statement. Something like: "start": "ng serve --port 41111 &REM"

Answer (score 2):

Try the following command:

`ng set defaults.serve.port=4201`

Comment: I guess that will work, but I am more a fan of a shared solution that multiple developers can use and be checked into version control instead of "please run this command first" solutions. Good tips though. Have a +1

Comment: Thanks for your comment and the +1

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you are correct, however I've seen a few other locations where this value might be overridden.  One would be in the package.json, specifically in this block:

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --sourcemap --extractCss --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

Also you might check in a file called proxy.config.json if you have it

Comment: Checked package.json, it doesn't explicitly specify a port and I don't have a  proxy.config.json.

Comment: It might have more to do with the dotnet command than anything in the angular config. check this out: https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/639

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in the `Startup` class (`Configure` method):

```cs
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
    // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

    spa.Options.SourcePath = "client";


    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.Options.DevServerPort = 4200;
        spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
}
```