# How to specify port number to use when launching Visual Studio 2019 Angular .NET Core template?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

The closest answer I found is this

[How to set a default port for ASP.NET Core Angular app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633863/how-to-set-a-default-port-for-asp-net-core-angular-app)

And

"start": "ng serve --hmr --o --port=1234 &REM",

But it doesn't work for kestral. And for IisExpress it loads the random port first.  I JUST WANT IT TO LOAD UP WITH PORT 1234. This seems like a simple thing to do. How do I get it working in IisExpress or Kestral ?

Comment: Are you trying to run your application on a specific port, or to run the Angular development server on a specific port?

Comment: the client because the ADFS server needed the requests t come from a particular port